# Error using Matlab parpool from Java

Tags: matlab

My system is Windows Server 2012 Standart R2, Matlab version is R2015a. I have tried [this example](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/pdc.kth.se/roots/ilse/v0.7/pdc/vol/matlab/r2014a/help/javabuilder/ug/improving-data-access-using-the-mcr-user-data-interface-and-matlab-builder-ja.html). When I run Java application it stops with the:

```
    Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local_mcruserdata' profile ... connected to 8 workers.
    Parallel pool using the 'local_mcruserdata' profile is shutting down.
    Error using parpool (line 103)
    Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the profile 'local_mcruserdata' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)

    Error in sample_pct (line 11)

    Caused by:
        Error using cd
        An internal error occurred during dctPathAndClearNotification.

    The error is `com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException`: Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the profile 'local_mcruserdata' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)
```

Profile 'local_mcruserdata' does not exist in my Cluster Profile Manager. I use local.settings file that was export profile 'local'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in R2015a. See http://uk.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1224308