# Error using Matlab parpool from Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, matlab

I need to use MATLAB library compiled to JAR file in my own Java application. That library uses `parpool` and has some `parfor` operators. We can use [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/java/supply-run-time-profile-information-for-parallel-computing-toolbox-applications.html) as a test.

On Windows it works. On Linux (Ubuntu xenial) I get the error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973933/error-using-matlab-parpool-from-java) but not the same:

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local_mcruserdata' profile ...

Error using parpool (line 104)
Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the profile 'local_mcruserdata' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)

Error in sample_pct (line 11)


Caused by:
    Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient>iThrowWithCause (line 666)
    Failed to initialize the interactive session.
        Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient>iThrowIfBadParallelJobStatus (line 767)
        The interactive communicating job failed with no message.

The error is com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the profile 'local_mcruserdata' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)
```

My MATLAB is 9.2.0.538062 (R2017a) and my JDK is 1.8.0_171 x86_64 on both systems.

If I comment line 11 (parpool function invocation) the error goes away but parfor operator does not create extra workers.

Is it a known bug and can it be fixed?

Comment: Hm, you might need to contact MathWorks support to help resolve this. You might try adding `setSchedulerMessageHandler(@disp); setenv('MDCE_DEBUG','true')` to your example to see if it uncovers more useful information.

Comment: @Edric, thanks for your advice!
This showed the message:
`matlabroot/bin/glnxa64/ctfxlauncher: error while loading shared libraries: libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `setSchedulerMessageHandler(@disp); setenv('MDCE_DEBUG','true')` to the example (as it was adviced in the comment) I have got the message:

`matlabroot/bin/glnxa64/ctfxlauncher: error while loading shared libraries: libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

`find matlabroot -name libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.2` gives `matlabroot/runtime/glnxa64/libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.2`

Adding `matlabroot/runtime/glnxa64` directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` helped!

Comment: It could be better to use `ld.so.conf` and `ldconfig` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but this variant still does not work (fails fith the error `Please install the correct version of the MATLAB Runtime`)